# Kotlin elegant way to mutate List<Triple<String, String, String> to Triple<List<String>, List<String>, List<String>>

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, monads, monad-transformers, arrow-kt

I'd like, as succinctly (yet clearly) as possible to transform a `List<Triple<String, String, String>` to a `Triple<List<String>, List<String>, List<String>>`.

For instance, say the method performing the transformation is called `turnOver`, I'd expect:

```kotlin
val matches = listOf(
  Triple("a", "1", "foo"),
  Triple("b", "2", "bar"),
  Triple("c", "3", "baz"),
  Triple("d", "4", "qux")
)
val expected = Triple(
  listOf("a", "b", "c", "d"),
  listOf("1", "2", "3", "4"),
  listOf("foo", "bar", "baz", "qux")
)
matches.turnOver() == expected // true
```

How to write a succinct, clear, and possibly functional `turnOver` function?

It's ok to use Arrow-Kt, I already got it as project dependency.

Comment: This operation is usually called an "unzip".

Comment: Yes, it's similar to an unzip, yet AFAIK, and at least in Kotlin, (un)zip applies to `List<Pair>`/`Pair<List>`. I'd like a generalized version, possibly working for n-tuples.

@alexey-romanov proposed `Traverse` from Arrow-Kt below, I'm gonna see if it fits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
fun turnOver(matches: List<Triple<String, String, String>>) = Triple(
   matches.map { it.first },
   matches.map { it.second },
   matches.map { it.third },
)
```

would be one obvious solution I reckon.

Comment: Nice, but in my mind I was thinking of a more generic solution, where code does not grow with the tuple size. I'm convinced there must be an idiom to to that kind of unwrapping in functional programming.

Comment: @DaniloPianini Since you mention Arrow-Kt, this is actually an application of `Traverse` (https://arrow-kt.io/docs/0.10/apidocs/arrow-core-data/arrow.typeclasses/-traverse/). But not with standard instances, so if you want to use it you'll have to still write a more general version of the above for each tuple size.

Comment: This solution performs `n` iterations over the `matches`, the `.unzip()` function for pairs performs only one as would iterating manually over them and adding the elements to `MutableList`s.

Answer (score -2):

To the best of my knowledge, there is no way in kotlin stdlib to create a Pair or a Triple out of an iterable, array, or sequence.  I believe this is deliberate. So I guess the one above is the clearest possible solution.

Comment: This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, a comment, another question, or deleted altogether. (But my flag was rejected.)